# same cookie on different pages (cookie path)

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, overriding

I have an application and I need to store some information in cookies. I have an index page and put some piece of information into cookie (for example, some variable name). Index page cookie has path `/Main/`. In another page I need to read this cookie and if necessary modify it. But another page cookie path is `/Main/info/`. Browser just creates a new cookie, but I need to override it and use the same cookie with path `/Main/` on all pages.
How can I do that?

Comment: How are you creating the cookie? Typically, cookies are per-domain not per-path.

Comment: I took this guide as an example: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

Comment: @Bob, sorry for this kind of question but how do you know your cookies have those pathes? Basically, if you don't specify cookies path they are in domain-scope.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, please accept one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Add **path=/;** or specify a path when you create the cookie.  This will prevent the browser from creating duplicate cookies per domain.

To one of the comments, if you look at Google Chrome and how it displays the cookies it will show you the path.  If you use the same cookie name without specifying the path it will create a cookie for each.

Note: Internet Explorer doesn't do the same thing, it has the single text file per domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should define one path for all `SET-COOKIE` commands independent of the sub-path of the requested resource (eg `path=/Main`). In general you should use the longest path possible... (but you will have to take a parent path of all resources using the same cookie).

Root (`/`) should be used only, if your application owns the complete domain and the cookie is needed for resources with different top level pathes (eg. `/main/...`, `/secondary/...` and `/unimportant/...`)

Why:

- Security Reasons
- Preventing Side-Effects with other applications on the same domain